# Help connecting ILI9341 LCD SPI Display to arduino uno

Tags: lcd

I got this lcd with touchscreen from a store but i have no idea on how to connect it to the arduino uno.
Any help is appreciated.

[This](https://www.optimusdigital.ro/ro/optoelectronice-lcd-uri/3544-modul-lcd-spi-de-28-cu-touchscreen-controller-ili9341-i-xpt2046-240x320-px.html?search_query=Modul%20LCD%20SPI%20de%202.8%27%27%20cu%20Touchscreen%20-%20Controller%20ILI9341%20%C8%99i%20XPT2046%20%28240x320%20px%29&results=1) is where i bought it from.

[The display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDTRI.jpg)

[My Arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3bmD.jpg)

Comment: your device uses two controllers. ILI9341 and XPT2046.

Comment: Maybe, then, you should buy your toys from somewhere that at least gives you a clue what to do with them. Anyway, the pins are clearly marked.

Comment: section 7.6 of the ILI9341 datasheet

Comment: @Majenko in romania this kind of resources are found in a very small amount of shops.

Comment: @jsotola i am new to this stuff, can you help me understand what is going on there?

Comment: @xM0nSt3r So buy from somewhere that isn't Romania?

Comment: @jsotola by resources i mean parts like lcds, arduinos or anything from this niche.

Comment: @jsotola i know it has that diagram but can i use transistors to lower the voltage instead that logic level translator?

Comment: why is your question so general?  please update your question to be more specific.  ask what you are really asking ... (deleting my useless comments) ....

Comment: do some research ... there is a lot of information on this website about converting 3.3V signals to 5V

Comment: @jsotola a'right i am going to look into it, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working by two methods

1. using a voltage divider e.g to shift from 5V to 3.3V you could use two resistors, 100k and 200k respecfully and between both resistors there is voltage of 3.3. One for each pin that needs it.
2. Using 10K resistors in series between the LCD and the arduino. I really don't know how is working but it works fine that way.

I tested both methods, also the MISO pin from the LCD can be connected directly to your arduino.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install a suitable library
2. Wire the display to the Arduino as per the markings on the display
3. Try some of the examples for the library you are using.

Comment: Can you give me more details about the wiring?

Comment: Read the words on the board and compare them to either the SPI manual page or the instructions for the library.

Comment: but can i use transistors to lower the voltage instead of that logic level translator?

Comment: Sorry, what are you talking about?

Comment: on the page i mentioned in the question it says i have to use [this](https://www.optimusdigital.ro/ro/interfata-convertoare-de-niveluri/1380-convertor-de-niveluri-logice-bidirecional-pe-8-bii-txs0108e.html)  to make it work, can i replace that with transistors?

Comment: Ah, it's a 3.3v display. You will need *something* to lower the 5V to 3.3V for the SPI signals. You may get away with resistive dividers, if you are lucky.

Comment: can you send me a link to those?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider